# Not able to setup comments functionality in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-comments

I am a novice in django. I am using `Django 1.8.3` & working on the functionality to add comment sections into blogs. 
But as there are lots of changes have taken place in Django's new releases (all the tutorials on net are considering `Django 1.6` or older) I am struggling to achieve my goal.
I have replaced `'django.contrib.comments'` with `'django_comments'` & `'django.contrib.sites'` in my settings.py .

Now after migrating those changes  When I am adding `url(r'^admin/', include("django.contrib.comments.urls")),` in my urls.py . It is giving me below error.

```
No module named comments.urls
```

Please help. Or if you can provide me any link which explains how Django comments work in Django 1.8. That would be awesome. 
Please let me know in case you need more information on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change `django.contrib.comments` to `django_comments` in your `urls.py` as well.

```
url(r'^admin/', include("django_comments.urls")),
```